# How to enable custom bitbucket jspm registry entry inside a Bamboo task?

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, bamboo, jspm

I currently have a Bamboo task that invokes jspm install from my local app's node_modules installation of jspm but the registry is missing.

The task errors out with "Registry bitbucket not found"

I assume this is because it's installing jspm in the scope of just the task and from that viewpoint the registry is never instantiated.

This is a new issue for me though and just recently started happening after I installed bamboo as a service. Previously, I had set up the registry local to the machine and it seems to have picked it up.

I don't have a working state that I can really revert back to however.

Has anyone else experienced issues with jspm registries in CI server tasks?

**Update 1:** I stuck a little sanity check in there to execute `node -e "console.log(process.env.LOCALAPPDATA || process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH)"` since this is where it looks for the global config anyways and found that the variable that gets used here is not always the same. Sometimes it's my user home (desirable) and other times it's the system's home path (undesirable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that's telling of what the issue is:

> This is a new issue for me though and just recently started happening
>   after I installed bamboo as a service. Previously, I had set up the
>   registry local to the machine and it seems to have picked it up.

Checking what user it was set to use in the services revealed that it was configured to use the local system account which is incorrect. Changing to use the properly configured user account resolves the problem.